# Why are there two objects created when I only really need one?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I just compiled this simple snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string foo()
{
    return std::string("bar");
}

int main()
{
    std::string test = foo();
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

using `-O2` optimization, only to discover that two std::string objects were being created. When I dump the binary, objdump shows that `~basic_string` is called twice.

```
0000000000400900 <main>:
  400900:   53                      push   %rbx
  400901:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  400905:   48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
  400908:   e8 73 01 00 00          callq  400a80 <foo()>
  40090d:   48 89 e6                mov    %rsp,%rsi
  400910:   bf 80 10 60 00          mov    $0x601080,%edi
  400915:   e8 a6 ff ff ff          callq  4008c0 <std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)@plt>
  40091a:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  40091d:   e8 ae ff ff ff          callq  4008d0 <std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)@plt>
  400922:   48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
  400925:   e8 76 ff ff ff          callq  4008a0 <std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()@plt>
  40092a:   48 83 c4 10             add    $0x10,%rsp
  40092e:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400930:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  400931:   c3                      retq   
  400932:   48 89 c3                mov    %rax,%rbx
  400935:   48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
  400938:   e8 63 ff ff ff          callq  4008a0 <std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()@plt>
  40093d:   48 89 df                mov    %rbx,%rdi
  400940:   e8 ab ff ff ff          callq  4008f0 <_Unwind_Resume@plt>
  400945:   66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00    data32 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40094c:   00 00 00 00
```

As I only really need one object, I thought about capturing the value `foo()` returned by using a rvalue reference. So I changed the line of code to `std::string && test = foo();` Weirdly, the objdump still shows two destructors called. Could anyone explain me why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first destructor call is followed a few instructions later by a `retq`:

> ```
>   400925:   e8 76 ff ff ff          callq  4008a0 <std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()@plt>
>   ...
>   400931:   c3                      retq
> ```

This is the *normal* flow of code.

Starting with the succeeding `mov` at `400932` is code internally used for unwinding the stack with exception propagation, often called the *landing pad*.

> ```
>   400932:   48 89 c3                mov    %rax,%rbx
>   400935:   48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
>   400938:   e8 63 ff ff ff          callq  4008a0 <std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()@plt>
>   40093d:   48 89 df                mov    %rbx,%rdi
>   400940:   e8 ab ff ff ff          callq  4008f0 <_Unwind_Resume@plt>
> ```

[Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gccint/RTL-passes.html)'s what GCC has to say:

> - Generate exception handling landing pads
>
>   This pass generates the glue that handles communication between the exception handling library routines and the exception handlers within the function. Entry points in the function that are invoked by the exception handling library are called *landing pads*. The code for this pass is located within `except.c`.

As you can see, the paths of control flow are completely distinct, so the destructor will only be called once either way.

`_Unwind_Resume` is apart of the AMD64 and Itanium C++ ABIs as a means of unwinding the call stack until it reaches a function capable of catching the exception type. You'll need to do a bit of digging to find much information on it from Google. [Here](http://www.ucw.cz/~hubicka/papers/abi/node25.html#SECTION00923300000000000000) is a pretty good resource which discusses it.

> _**Unwind_Resume**
>
> ```
> void _Unwind_Resume
> (struct _Unwind_Exception *exception_object);
> ```
>
> Resume propagation of an existing exception e.g. after executing cleanup code in a partially unwound stack. A call to this routine is inserted at the end of a landing pad that performed cleanup, but did not resume normal execution. It causes unwinding to proceed further.
>
> `_Unwind_Resume` should not be used to implement rethrowing. To the unwinding runtime, the catch code that rethrows was a handler, and the previous unwinding session was terminated before entering it. Rethrowing is implemented by calling `_Unwind_RaiseException` again with the same exception object.
>
> This is the only routine in the unwind library which is expected to be called directly by generated code: it will be called at the end of a landing pad in a "landing-pad" model.